# Laravel 5.2 RethinkDB Service Provider Preventing Creation of Migration Files

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I followed the installation to install this service provider, but each time I try to create a migration file I get this error:

```
  [ErrorException]
  Argument 2 passed to duxet\Rethinkdb\Console\Migrations\MigrateMakeCommand::__construct() must be an instance
   of Illuminate\Foundation\Composer, instance of Illuminate\Support\Composer given, called in D:\projects\app\vendor\duxet\laravel-rethinkdb\src\RethinkdbServiceProvider.php on line 41 and defined
```

I'm on line 41 and can see that the second parameter is `$composer`, which equals `$composer = $app['composer'];`.  I thought maybe changing `Illuminate\Support\Composer` to `Illuminate\Foundation\ServiceProvider` might just fix the issue, but doing this throws another error saying that:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\ServiceProvider' not found
```

Anyone running into this issue?

**Update**

Where the original error is occurring (I marked Line 41):

```
<?php

namespace duxet\Rethinkdb;

use duxet\Rethinkdb\Console\Migrations\MigrateMakeCommand;
use duxet\Rethinkdb\Eloquent\Model;
use duxet\Rethinkdb\Migrations\MigrationCreator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class RethinkdbServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application events.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Model::setConnectionResolver($this->app['db']);
        Model::setEventDispatcher($this->app['events']);
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->resolving('db', function ($db) {
            $db->extend('rethinkdb', function ($config) {
                return new Connection($config);
            });
        });

        $this->app->singleton('command.rethink-migrate.make', function ($app) {

            $creator = new MigrationCreator($app['files']);
            $composer = $app['composer'];

            return new MigrateMakeCommand($creator, $composer); <= line 41
        });

        $this->commands('command.rethink-migrate.make');
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return ['command.rethink-migrate.make'];
    }
}
```

The MigrateMakeCommand class:

```
<?php

namespace duxet\Rethinkdb\Console\Migrations;

use duxet\Rethinkdb\Migrations\MigrationCreator;
use Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateMakeCommand as LaravelMigration;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Composer;

class MigrateMakeCommand extends LaravelMigration
{
    /**
     * The console command signature.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'make:rethink-migration {name : The name of the migration.}
        {--create= : The table to be created.}
        {--table= : The table to migrate.}
        {--path= : The location where the migration file should be created.}';

    /**
     * Create a new migration install command instance.
     *
     * @param duxet\Rethinkdb\Migrations\MigrationCreator $creator
     * @param \Illuminate\Foundation\Composer             $composer
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(MigrationCreator $creator, Composer $composer)
    {
        parent::__construct($creator, $composer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhere, a service provider is registering `'composer'` - It will be something like: `$this->app->bind('composer', ...`. That class, needs to implement or extend the instance of `Illuminate\Foundation\Composer`

Comment: Hi @ash, I did search in this package and the only other file that contains composer is their `MigrateMakeCommand`, it injects `Illuminate\Foundation\Composer` into the constructor, but already extends LaravelMigration.  I'd implement the Class, but I don't think it's an interface.  I posted the class `MigrateMakeCommand` above in case that helps.

Comment: most likely its related to the fact that laravel has changed composer class from `Illuminate\Foundation\Composer` to `Illuminate\Support\Composer` any way will check it.

Comment: Hi @zaherg, yep I changed `Illuminate\Foundation\Composer` to `Illuminate\Support\Composer` in the RethinkDB `MigrateMakeCommand` and it just migrated my users table.

Comment: hi @mtpultz I just sent them a pull request